# forwarding from spring controller to a jsp file

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to forward my request from a Spring-MVC controller method - to a JSP page.

My controller method is supposed to **handle an Ajax request**. By **forwarding the request to the JSP file**, I want the response to the Ajax request to be the (dynamic) HTML **output of the JSP file**.

What I have tried:

```
public ModelAndView ajaxResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    request.setAttribute("command", "hello world");

    request.getRequestDispatcher("jspfile").forward(request, response);
    return null;    
}
```

This fails and I get "HTTP Status 404"

"jspfiles" is defined in a tiles config file to be directed to the actual jsp file. When I run the following method:

```
public String ajaxResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    request.setAttribute("command", "hello world");
    return "jspfile";
}
```

... I get the content of the file as my Ajax response - but JSP tags in that file are not parsed) - hence I conclude that my tiles definition is correct (???).

My JSP file looks like this:

```
<%=command%>
```

So I want to get as my Ajax response the string "hello world".

Could you show me an example code of how to achieve my purpose?

Specifically I need to know:

1. What should be the controller method return type?
2. What should be the controller method actual return value (if it matters)?
3. How should I set the jsp file path in the `request.getRequestDispatcher(...)` so it would be recognized?

Comment: Your second controller looks correct to me - what happens if you browse to the URL that invokes that method instead of making an ajax request for it?  does the JSP display properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the controller example here:
http://maestric.com/doc/java/spring/mvc

It's a bit out of date, but the concept of what you must do remains the same.  Spring 3 has annotation-based ways to do a lot of what is in that example.

Comment: You are correct. I don't actually need to use in my case the `request.getRequestDispatcher("jspfile").forward(request, response);` - as the forwarding to the jsp is done automatically by the framework.